# OS X Yosemite Configure: checking whether the C compiler works... no

Tags: macos, haskell, gcc, osx-yosemite, configure

I've been trying to install a Haskell library with cabal install but I encounter a problem where configure fails. Example output is as follows:

```
~ ❯ cabal install MissingH
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring old-time-1.1.0.3...
Configuring network-2.6.2.1...
Failed to install old-time-1.1.0.3
Build log ( /Users/samuel/.cabal/logs/old-time-1.1.0.3.log ):
Configuring old-time-1.1.0.3...
configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --with-compiler, --with-gcc
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/private/var/folders/11/b322xxjj7nn_46hvcr095m140000gn/T/cabal-tmp-11323/old-time-1.1.0.3':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
Failed to install network-2.6.2.1
Build log ( /Users/samuel/.cabal/logs/network-2.6.2.1.log ):
Configuring network-2.6.2.1...
configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --with-compiler, --with-gcc
checking build system type... x86_64-apple-darwin14.5.0
checking host system type... x86_64-apple-darwin14.5.0
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/private/var/folders/11/b322xxjj7nn_46hvcr095m140000gn/T/cabal-tmp-11322/network-2.6.2.1':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
MissingH-1.3.0.1 depends on network-2.6.2.1 which failed to install.
hslogger-1.2.9 depends on network-2.6.2.1 which failed to install.
network-2.6.2.1 failed during the configure step. The exception was:
ExitFailure 77
old-time-1.1.0.3 failed during the configure step. The exception was:
ExitFailure 77
```

Googling the problem (and searching this site) shows that the most common fix appears to be to update the Xcode command line tools. I tried that and I'm now on Xcode 7.2 and there's no pending updates, but I still get the same problem. Some answers said to make sure to accept the updated license after installation, which I have also done. I also tried installing gcc using homebrew and tried changing the `CC` path variable and using the `--with-gcc` option for cabal. All with no luck. I've run out of ideas.

### Update

Additional info requested by user2407038: Cabal install seems to clean up after itself, but here's the `config.log` file for trying to build just one dependancies (old-time) of the command shown above. Seems to be missing `-lgcc_ext.10.4` which a quick google suggests in an Xcode update thing?

```
This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

It was created by Haskell old-time package configure 1.0, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.69.  Invocation command line was

  $ ./configure --with-compiler=ghc --prefix=/Users/samuel/.cabal --with-gcc=/usr/local/bin/gcc

## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##

hostname = jackel.lan
uname -m = x86_64
uname -r = 14.5.0
uname -s = Darwin
uname -v = Darwin Kernel Version 14.5.0: Tue Sep  1 21:23:09 PDT 2015; root:xnu-2782.50.1~1/RELEASE_X86_64

/usr/bin/uname -p = i386
/bin/uname -X     = unknown

/bin/arch              = unknown
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
/usr/bin/hostinfo      = Mach kernel version:
     Darwin Kernel Version 14.5.0: Tue Sep  1 21:23:09 PDT 2015; root:xnu-2782.50.1~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel configured for up to 4 processors.
2 processors are physically available.
4 processors are logically available.
Processor type: x86_64h (Intel x86-64h Haswell)
Processors active: 0 1 2 3
Primary memory available: 8.00 gigabytes
Default processor set: 224 tasks, 1045 threads, 4 processors
Load average: 1.80, Mach factor: 2.18
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown

PATH: /Users/samuel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin
PATH: /Users/samuel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/bin
PATH: /Users/samuel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin
PATH: /usr/local/bin
PATH: /usr/bin
PATH: /bin
PATH: /usr/sbin
PATH: /sbin
PATH: /usr/local/bin
PATH: /usr/bin
PATH: /bin
PATH: /usr/sbin
PATH: /sbin
PATH: /opt/X11/bin
PATH: /usr/texbin
PATH: /Users/samuel/.rvm/bin
PATH: /Users/samuel/scripts


## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:2256: checking for gcc
configure:2272: found /usr/local/bin/gcc
configure:2283: result: gcc
configure:2512: checking for C compiler version
configure:2521: gcc --version >&5
gcc (GCC) 4.9.0 20140309 (experimental)
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

gcc: warning: couldn't understand kern.osversion '14.5.0
configure:2532: $? = 0
configure:2521: gcc -v >&5
gcc: warning: couldn't understand kern.osversion '14.5.0
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/local/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin13.1.0/4.9.0/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.1.0
Configured with: ../gcc-4.9-20140309/configure --enable-languages=fortran,c++
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.9.0 20140309 (experimental) (GCC) 
configure:2532: $? = 0
configure:2521: gcc -V >&5
gcc: warning: couldn't understand kern.osversion '14.5.0
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-V'
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:2532: $? = 1
configure:2521: gcc -qversion >&5
gcc: warning: couldn't understand kern.osversion '14.5.0
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-qversion'
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:2532: $? = 1
configure:2552: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:2574: gcc    conftest.c  >&5
gcc: warning: couldn't understand kern.osversion '14.5.0
ld: library not found for -lgcc_ext.10.4
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
configure:2578: $? = 1
configure:2616: result: no
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "Haskell old-time package"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "old-time"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "1.0"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "Haskell old-time package 1.0"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "libraries@haskell.org"
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
| int
| main ()
| {
| 
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:2621: error: in `/Users/samuel/old-time-1.1.0.3':
configure:2623: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details

## ---------------- ##
## Cache variables. ##
## ---------------- ##

ac_cv_env_CC_set=
ac_cv_env_CC_value=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_set=set
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPP_set=
ac_cv_env_CPP_value=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_value=
ac_cv_prog_ac_ct_CC=gcc

## ----------------- ##
## Output variables. ##
## ----------------- ##

CC='gcc'
CFLAGS=''
CPP=''
CPPFLAGS=''
DEFS=''
ECHO_C='\c'
ECHO_N=''
ECHO_T=''
EGREP=''
EXEEXT=''
GREP=''
LDFLAGS=''
LIBOBJS=''
LIBS=''
LTLIBOBJS=''
OBJEXT=''
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT='libraries@haskell.org'
PACKAGE_NAME='Haskell old-time package'
PACKAGE_STRING='Haskell old-time package 1.0'
PACKAGE_TARNAME='old-time'
PACKAGE_URL=''
PACKAGE_VERSION='1.0'
PATH_SEPARATOR=':'
SHELL='/bin/sh'
ac_ct_CC='gcc'
bindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
build_alias=''
datadir='${datarootdir}'
datarootdir='${prefix}/share'
docdir='${datarootdir}/doc/${PACKAGE_TARNAME}'
dvidir='${docdir}'
exec_prefix='NONE'
host_alias=''
htmldir='${docdir}'
includedir='${prefix}/include'
infodir='${datarootdir}/info'
libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib'
libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/libexec'
localedir='${datarootdir}/locale'
localstatedir='${prefix}/var'
mandir='${datarootdir}/man'
oldincludedir='/usr/include'
pdfdir='${docdir}'
prefix='/Users/samuel/.cabal'
program_transform_name='s,x,x,'
psdir='${docdir}'
sbindir='${exec_prefix}/sbin'
sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
sysconfdir='${prefix}/etc'
target_alias=''

## ----------- ##
## confdefs.h. ##
## ----------- ##

/* confdefs.h */
#define PACKAGE_NAME "Haskell old-time package"
#define PACKAGE_TARNAME "old-time"
#define PACKAGE_VERSION "1.0"
#define PACKAGE_STRING "Haskell old-time package 1.0"
#define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "libraries@haskell.org"
#define PACKAGE_URL ""

configure: exit 77
```

The output for `cabal install MissingH -v3` is too long to fit in the body of the question, but I posted it [here](https://gist.github.com/samueljackson92/26c4f1d5a32a617267ea)

Comment: There is very little information here, have you identified which portion of the "C compiler" is failing and how? What are the contents of "config.log"? Have you run any of these commands with `-v3`? Have you possibly got multiple versions of gcc or something on your path? With basically 0 information to go on, this seems the most likely explanation to me.

Comment: Just because you have Xcode 7.2 installed it doesn't mean that you have also installed the command line tools. Try `xcode-select --install` at a terminal prompt.

Comment: user2407038 I've added some extra info as you suggested. I did have another version of gcc installed via homebrew, an I suspected as you did. But I uninstalled homebrew gcc and did a quick `brew list` to check I got them all, but still no luck.

Comment: @PaulR That command outputs: `xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates`

Comment: Double check that your PATH is OK - do a `which gcc` to see what it returns.

Comment: `which gcc` gives me `/usr/local/bin/gcc`. Should it perhaps be pointing to `/usr/bin/gcc`?

Comment: Yes it sounds like you didn't uninstall your homebrew gcc properly - it's probably a dangling symbolic link - get rid of it and try again.

Comment: Pointed it at the correct version and it now works. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Turns out to that despite removing all Homebrew versions of gcc I still had another version installed at `/usr/local/bin/gcc` which was overriding the apple default.